# Can SQL Server Registered Servers be Used in SQL Agent Jobs without having to hack the registry on each server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server's Registered Servers functionality is an ideal way for me to question multiple servers and put the output into a table / excel file.  The Registered Servers functionality works perfect when I manually run a query.

However, I have run into problems when trying to write an agent job to use Registered Servers.  Other threads have suggested using "Multi Server Administration" on SQL Server Agent.  My problem with this is that it fails to MSX Enlist 'new server. into 'my master'.

A workaround for this involves editing the registry on each server.  However, it is not feasible for me to be hacking Registry Settings, plus I'm sure that will subsequently create some security issues.

Does anybody know of a way to create a scheduled job that uses the Registered Servers?

I'm currently using 2008r2 but also have access to 2012 if required?

Many thanks,
Stevie

Comment: Can you specify what you want to achieve.? Do you want that Sql Server Agent from one server has access to other servers? Can you just script the job you want to distribute from one server and execute this script on rest (this way you get the same jobs there) via Registered Server?

Comment: Consider using [Automated Administration Across an Enterprise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180992.aspx)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply lad2025.  To start with, I am running a simple script which returns monitoring information (e.g.  dbsizes, free space etc) about all databases & servers and stores them in a single table.  The purpose of this is to provide a single source whereby this can be monitored, currently the system uses an SSRS report on each individual server.  Which seems cumbersome to look through.  I have looked at powershell but I really like the way in which Registered Servers stores the information in one table and thus allows the user to query using SQL commands.

Comment: In the future, I would look at performing more advanced commands (but I am wary of performing anything that could potentially alter several databases across several servers).

Comment: the Automated Administration looks like exactly the kind of thing I need BUT I would have to manually edit the Registry on a number of servers, which is a non-starter as it is not feasible for this current project.

Comment: Registered Servers **don't store result in one table**, this is only eye candy for SSMS. When you run query you get result from multiple sources and then it is concatenated to show you. Just try to insert that result somewhere.

Comment: If I insert / select the information into a table....that would store it in one place wouldn't it?

Comment: `SELECT * INTO #temp FROM` run on multiple nodes and check where data goes. Answer: Data will be in temp table in respective database. You will get at all registered server target one temp table with chunk data.

Comment: no way!  Stored in the master database (or tempDb - depending on type of table) on each server.  Thanks for your help with this, it really is appreciated.  I'm not sure I want to be storing data in the master databases across all servers, that could get massively out of hand.  However, if I were to store data in a table on each master database, I could run a job on each individual server and then I could use Registered Servers as a way to concatenate the data into one place (for visual purposes).

Comment: Nor do I really want to be adding a lot of data onto the tempdb.
However, I still have reservations about creating tables on the master database, should I have reason to be concerned?

Comment: Why do create table at all? Can you just on one server (main for fetching data) define [linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) to other databases, query data using `SELECT * FROM [linked_server].[database_name].[schema].[table] UNION ALL SELECT * FROM [linked_server2].[database_name].[schema].[table] UNION ALL ...` and INSERT INTO one table on one designed database.

Comment: Thanks again for this.  From a security standpoint, are linked servers generally to be avoided?  I'm trying to simplify processes here but do not really want o compromise security (which obviously becomes an issue when running queries on multiple servers).

Comment: Using Linked Server you have to set credentials, you can for instance create new ueser on remote servers, user which has restricted access only to specific database and tables in read-only mode, so anyone cannot elevate them.